# How to know if a certain container has a software/package installed or not?

Tags: docker

I use Gradient notebooks, they grab the container from a URL and files from a Github repo and combine them to make Notebook instance.

Something like this one.
[image]

However, the container image from this URL (nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:21.09-tf2-py3), which I use to learn Tensorflow does not have sklearn and matplotlib.

I need to install sklearn and matplotlib every single time using pip. I thought why not grab an images with all basic packages and Tensorflow. But on Docker's website (https://hub.docker.com/search?q=tensorflow&type=image&image_filter=store), how do I check the softwares inside the images. I know if I search Tensorflow I get images of Tensorflow, but how do I check if they have matplotlib and sklearn.

I know I can make my own container, but I just want to save my time with verified publishers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the packages in a container by exec to it:
docker exec  pip list